# Detect css changes (mutationObserver on styleSheet css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mutation-observers

Is there a way to detect stylesheet changes ? MutationObserver only tracks inline css changes on the element.

html

```
<div class="exampleClass"></div>
```

js

```
let config = {
    attributes: true,
    // attributeFilter: ["style"],
  };

  let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList) {
    mutationsList.forEach((mutation, i) => {
      console.log(mutation);
    });
  };
  let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('.exampleClass'), config);
```

If I modify the element throught js with

```
document.querySelector(‘exampleClass’).style.top = '10px'
```

or the webconsole inspector directly on the node, the mutation observer callback is called, but if the class (not the node itself) is modified in the webconsole inspector there is no callback

Comment: It will only help if the changes are applied via textContent but not if it's via `sheet.insertRule` or `adoptedStyleSheets`. There are dirty ways to intercept those by overriding the API functions but maybe there's another solution - why do you want to detect these changes? How these changes are made? If it's only for console changes then why?

Comment: In the project I'm working on, changes made on the css have a live influence on the sound coming out of the webpage. Changes are made in the webconsole inspector